# How to insert spaces and blank lines in either python or bash

Tags: python, bash, yaml

I have a yaml file that I want to insert blank lines into using either python or bash. Here is what the file looks like:

```
---

something:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
more_stuff:
- name1
- name2
- name3
- name4

...
```

However, this is not what yaml is supposed to look like. I am in this situation because I am using the yaml library for python and there is no way to get the spacing and indexing right without using some random person's custom made library, which I do not want to do. I've have exhausted all my ideas for how to do this with python, and I am sure there is a way to do this in bash but I am painfully terrible with bash. I need an extra space between the 'something' and 'more_stuff' lists and I need two spaces before each '-' in the second list. Here is what I want the file to look like:

```
---

something:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2

more_stuff:
  - name1
  - name2
  - name3
  - name4

...
```

If anyone has any suggestions I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: `However, this is not what yaml is supposed to look like.` Says who? Certainly not the YAML standard. Either of those will parse fine in any conformant library implementation.

Comment: `yaml.dump` has multiple parameters to change its output format and you can supply as `Dumper` object as well. I don't know if these cover all of your cases, but worth a look.

Comment: Regarding `I am sure there is a way to do this in bash` - no, there isn't. You can't do it with bash builtins and the tools you could call from bash (maybe `yq`?) could be categorized as some random person's custom made tool to do it.

Comment: This does seem like valid yaml per @SilvioMayolo original comment.  But if you really want to change it according to the conditions you mentioned, then the following might suffice: `awk '/more_stuff:/ { printf "\n%s\n", $0; next} /^- / {$1=""; printf "  -%s", $1;}1' your_file.yml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a text file "data.txt" as input as follows:

```
something:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2
more_stuff:
- name1
- name2
- name3
- name4
```

You can run the following Python script:

```
f = open("data.txt", "r")

result = open("result.txt", "w")

result.write("---\n")

for line in f:
    line = line[:-1]
    if(line[0] != " " and line[0] != "-"):
        result.write("\n" + line + "\n")
    elif(line[0] == "-"):
        result.write("  " + line + "\n")
    else:
        result.write(line + "\n")
```

And generate the output file, "result.txt" as follows:

```
---

something:
  key1: value1
  key2: value2

more_stuff:
  - name1
  - name2
  - name3
  - name
```

Comment: And you're confident this will handle all yaml block styles? It seems like you brute force this one example, but what about a multiline string or other multiline data structure?

Comment: There could be edge cases! But the question specifically mentions changes of this kind! And the script could further be refined easily to cater for multiline structures too. And again, as per one of the comments on the question, its all the same for the parser.